# Command recall within bash/ksh script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ksh

Suppose I have an interactive script with the following inside:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
...
while read -p "> " CMD
do
        ...
        ...
done
...
...
```

Is it possible to implement a "command recall"? I want to press the up-arrow key and run a previously entered command.

Comment: BTW, this has also been asked on our sister site [unix.se] at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52091/read-with-history

Comment: In bash `!!` will repeat the previous command if that's what you mean...

Comment: hmm. `read -e` will give you line editing capability, but up/down arrows use your command history, which will be unavailable in a script.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to recall commands within a `bash` script.  Here's a script `hist.sh` that runs a command given a relative offset backwards in the `bash` history:

```
#!/bin/bash 
HISTFILE=$(mktemp bhXXXXXX)
set -o history
shopt -s expand_aliases
alias e=:
e one
e two
e three
e four
e five
e six
alias e=echo
EDITOR=: fc -n $((HISTCMD - (2+$1) )) 2> /dev/null | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'
rm $HISTFILE
```

Save it, and test by feeding it a number from 1 to 6:

```
hist.sh 5
hist.sh 1
```

Output:

```
TWO
SIX
```

---

Notes:

- The `e` and `alias` stuff is cosmetic, it shortens the output.  The first time `e six` runs for example, `bash` interprets it as `: six` which does nothing.  The second time `e six` runs, `bash` interprets it as `echo six`.
- In scripts history and aliases don't work by default, so `set` and `shopt` reactivate them.
- `$HISTFILE` is set to a temporary file, so the history applies to this script only.
- `fc` can run any command in the history, but it needs to be fed an absolute number, like *345*.  But when the history gets full, these numbers scroll up, so the command that was *345* after one command becomes *344* after another.  The current command number is stored in `$HISTCMD`, which is used here to compute an offset.
- `fc` ordinarily sends the command to a text editor before running it.  Setting `$EDITOR` to a do-nothing command like `:` prevents that.
- `tr` is used to convert text to upper case, which helps show that `fc` is actually working.

Comment: What's interesting about the cosmetic part is that `alias`es can be used as a crude form of [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)), which `bash` functions alone can't do.